# Python: call the same function with the same arguments several times, or save the result as an intermediate value?

Tags: python, performance

If I have a function

```
def bar(n):
    return n**100
```

Would there be a performance difference between

```
for i in range(1000000):
    x = bar(30)
    # use x for something
```

and

```
x = bar(30)
# use x for something 1,000,000 times
```

I don't know if the interpreter has been optimized for cases like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Python optimize function calls from loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243444/does-python-optimize-function-calls-from-loops)

Comment: Also note that in imperative programming languages, multiple call to a function with the same arguments may have completely different effects. Proving that some such calls can be omitted may require significant inter-procedural analysis, and inlining them requires either early binding (which simply *does not exist* in Python) and an optimizing compiler, or a JIT compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CPython compiler only does very few simple [peephole optimisations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization), but it will certainly never optimise away a function call -- how would it know if the function has side effects anyway?  At compilation time, it usually doesn't even know which function the name `bar` refers to, and the name binding might change at any time.

If in doubt, simply measure the performance yourself -- the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the implementation. Pypy added [loop invariant code motion](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/01/loop-invariant-code-motion.html) in version [1.5](http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2011/04/pypy-15-released-catching-up.html).